# Using Android ble sdk in android emulator to connect to BLE dongle

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to test the bluetooth low-energy application in Android virtual device.

I have the following working

1. I have bluetooth enabled Android emulator running in Virtualbox.(android-x86). Its scanning all the bluetooth devices in the settings option correctly.
2. I have a BLE bluetooth dongle(4.0).
3. Have a sample code of ble from Android 4.3.

Now i want to develop a simple application to get the UUID of the bluetooth LowEnergy device.

Now my questions are

1. I run the sample code in the emulator but its showing BLE is not supported but actually the settings menu is showing all the devices.
   How to resolve this?

Comment: Is it possible or not?

Comment: Regarding the Android, I'd recommend trying [Androidx86 latest image with Android 4.3](http://www.android-x86.org/releases/build-20130725) using the new Android API (which should support BLE) instead of the Samsung SDK. Still, I am not sure if it is going to work. Trying it here, I got some problems here trying to turn on the blueetooth on the Androidx86, but Im afraid it may be issues of the broadcom's bluetooth windows 7 driver, as apparently ble support in win came recently in [win 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj159880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Thomas thanks for your reply. let me try

Comment: I edited the question since the Android 4.3 is released. so i run the sample code in the virtual device but its saying that "BLE is not supported" in the virtual device. @Thomas pls help me out in this.

Comment: @Prakash Did you ever figure this out?  I am wondering the same right now.